# doing jquery pagination on anchor tags having javascript functions instead of links?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-pagination

I am having some anchor tags each calling some javascript function on click(they have href as #), If iam doing pagination, it will generate only links however I want to call javascript functions instead of links for eg,

```
<a href="#" onclick="openVideo(parameters);">video</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openpdf(parameters);">pdf</a>
<a href="#" onclick="openquiz(parameters);">quiz</a>
```

How can i paginate them using jquery ajax pagination. Iam using codeigniter 2.1.4.

Comment: Do you just want to prevent hashing the URL?

Comment: no I wanted to create previous and next <- -> links when clicked will go between the three links and executes the JS functions for eg. at first instance onclick next video should open and only then <- will be active. this way I want to bring.Thanks